# Show and hide divs with JS

Tags: javascript

I have 5 `<a>`...

```
<a id="showtrips">TRIPS</a>
<a id="showeats">EATS</a>
<a id="showfilms">FILMS</a>
<a id="showmusic">MUSIC</a>
<a id="showtravels">TRAVELS</a>
```

...and I have 5 `<div>` and each div have the content of the `<a>` names. I want show all `<a>` and show only a `<div>`, so I want click on a `<a>` and hide the others divs showing only the selected div.

I'm searching and searching but I can´t find this exactly I found similar things but impossible to integrate to this problem.

This are the divs tags

```
<div id="trips">Content  Trips</div>
<div id="eats">Content  Eats</div>
<div id="films">Content  Films</div>
<div id="music">Content  Music</div>
<div id="travels">Content  Travels</div>

#trips{ display: block };
#eats{ display: none };
#films{ display: none };
#music{ display: none };
#travels{ display: none };
```

Comment: Where are the `<div>` tags? is every `a` tag wrapped with a `div` ?

Comment: You'll need to add some more code to this, we'd need to see the divs

Comment: @zfrisch the div tag are no written but yes each a tag have her div

Comment: Please share your full code. And, if possible please edit your problem to make it easy to understand what you are looking for !!

Comment: @OliverRadini Done that is the code I have, I have not js code because I cant find some to add on js and do work it

Comment: @BishalGautam Done that is the code I have, I have not js code because I cant find some to add on js and do work it

Comment: @BishalGautam Check now

Comment: @OliverRadini better now?

Comment: The problem with this question that I have is that you've done no legwork of your own. Putting the `a` tags inside of the `div` tags is the least that you could've done, but your attempt seems to showcase that you're unsure of what you're doing and you've done no research on your own. It's understandable in a way if you're new to markup, and I'd encourage you to check out some tutorials, but for StackOverflow it's required that you attempt a problem to an at least rudimentary level, and at that point post a question. This keeps StackOverflow from being a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, though this hides *all* `div`s on click, apart from the `div` matching the `a` tag. I'd suggest adding something to identify the `div`s to show/hide. This only requires vanilla js.

```js
const test = document
  .querySelectorAll('[id*="show"]')
  .forEach(element => element.onclick = () => {
    document
      .querySelectorAll('div')
      .forEach(element => {
        element.style.display = 'none';
      });
  
    const divIdToShow = element.id.replace('show', '');
    const divElementToShow = document.getElementById(divIdToShow);
    divElementToShow.style.display = 'block';
    

  });

console.log(test)
```

```css
#trips {
  display: block;
}

#eats {
  display: none;
}

#films {
  display: none;
}

#music {
  display: none;
}

#travels {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="showtrips">TRIPS</a>
<a id="showeats">EATS</a>
<a id="showfilms">FILMS</a>
<a id="showmusic">MUSIC</a>
<a id="showtravels">TRAVELS</a>

<div id="trips">Content  Trips</div>
<div id="eats">Content  Eats</div>
<div id="films">Content  Films</div>
<div id="music">Content  Music</div>
<div id="travels">Content  Travels</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver this really just help me working perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simple javascript you can toggle the div using the following code:

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (mydiv.style.display === "none") {
    mydiv.style.display = "block";
} else {
    mydiv.style.display = "none";
}
```

If you using jQuery you can directly use toggle methods.

```
$( ".target" ).toggle();
```

I suggest you group your div and anchor tags using the class name, So it will be easy to maintain.

Your html code will be like:

```
<a id="showtrips" class="link">TRIPS</a>
<a id="showeats" class="link">EATS</a>
<a id="showfilms" class="link">FILMS</a>
<a id="showmusic" class="link">MUSIC</a>
<a id="showtravels" class="link">TRAVELS</a>

<div id="trips" class="content">Content  Trips</div>
<div id="eats" class="content">Content  Eats</div>
<div id="films" class="content">Content  Films</div>
<div id="music" class="content">Content  Music</div>
<div id="travels" class="content">Content  Travels</div>
```

Your JS code will be look like:

```
document
  .querySelectorAll('[class="link"]')
  .forEach(element => element.onclick = () => {
    document
      .querySelectorAll('[class="content"]')
      .forEach(element => {
        element.style.display = 'none';
      });
    const mydiv = element.id.substr(4);
    document.getElementById(mydiv).style.display = 'block'; 
  });
```

I just created the working jsfiddle for you link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k98qtrps/15/)

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial. You have 2 options: either add "onclick" events on each of your  tags and then listen to these events with js. Or, since you added ids to each of your  tags, you can now attach click events to them with js.

So, no more words. Here's the simple solution:

```js
document.getElementById("showtrips").onclick = toggleShowForElement(document.getElementById("trips"));

document.getElementById("showeats").onclick = toggleShowForElement(document.getElementById("eats"));

document.getElementById("showfilms").onclick = toggleShowForElement(document.getElementById("films"));

document.getElementById("showmusic").onclick = toggleShowForElement(document.getElementById("music"));

document.getElementById("showtravels").onclick = toggleShowForElement(document.getElementById("travels"));

function toggleShowForElement(element) {
  return () => {
    if (element.style.display === "none") {
       element.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       element.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #008800;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div {
  background-color: #88DD99;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a id="showtrips">TRIPS</a>
<a id="showeats">EATS</a>
<a id="showfilms">FILMS</a>
<a id="showmusic">MUSIC</a>
<a id="showtravels">TRAVELS</a>

<div id="trips">Content  Trips</div>
<div id="eats">Content  Eats</div>
<div id="films">Content  Films</div>
<div id="music">Content  Music</div>
<div id="travels">Content  Travels</div>
```

Just added a bit of CSS to make it look a bit prettier. It's not needed here.